# Duplicate tree-level description in CLI prompt

Tags: command-line, prompt

I am writing a tool that enables a user to traverse a tree-structured data set, which describes a set of roads, each road can have `n` lanes.

The idle, starting prompt looks like this:

> Jeep@CurrentlyDriving>

The user can then traverse to other roads using the DRIVE command

> Jeep@CurrentlyDriving> DRIVE Road1
>
> Jeep@CurrentlyDriving\Road1>

The user has the ability to change lanes using the LANE command.

#### The problem

Should the user use the LANE command (but only if he does so), I want to CLI to reflect that change, i.e, show that a lane has been changed since entering a certain road.
i.e,

> Jeep@CurrentlyDriving\Road1> LANE 1
>
> Jeep@CurrentlyDriving\Road1????????>

What would be the best way to reflect the lane change (should be reflected where the ???`s are) without significantly 'damaging' the CLI structure?

Answer (score 0):

#### Assumptions on usability requirements

Short recap what I understood: in your CLI

- the *promt* adapts to user-input given by commands
- the *user* should view the current state, i.e. reflect valid commands issued like `Road 1` or `Lane 1`
- the issued commands build a *chain/hierarchy* that can be visualized like a *path* (tree structure)

#### Visualize the path: commands

A *path* usually is visualized as concatenation of *path-segments* separated by a distinctive **separator**. Compare this to:

- the bread-crumbs used on web pages to show the current position within the page hierarchy
- a folder-path displayed in unix-like shell-prompts

This **path visualization** can also be applied here, e.g using given slash `\` as *separator*:

```
Jeep@CurrentlyDriving\Road1> LANE 1
Jeep@CurrentlyDriving\Road1\Lane1>
```

#### Visualize further details: arguments

To further distinguish the actual *command* (here: `LANE`) from its *argument* or parameter you could insert additional separators. For example a colon `:` would reveal command details like this:

```
Jeep@CurrentlyDriving\Road:1> LANE 1
Jeep@CurrentlyDriving\Road:1\Lane:1>
```

Hope I understood your question & requirements correctly and my suggested visualization supports them.